# Basic question of "good" habits during the evaluation of a notebook in mathematica

Tags: compile, compiler

Suppose that I have notebook, call it Nb1. And I want to evaluate  the notebook Nb1, next suppose that the process is slow, but I have to evaluate other notebooks, suppose Nb2, and Nb3. I see that mathematica let me run the notebook Nb2, and Nb3 at the same time that Nb1.

**Question**

I can run Nb1, Nb2, and Nb3 at the same time, but should I do it?

I mean, the probability of altering the results of Nb1 because I run other process at the same time is 0?

Should I evaluate Nb2 and Nb3, after the process Nb1 stops?

Comment: You don't mean compilation - you mean evaluation. _Mathematica_ appears to either lock a mutex or at least prevent reads in another notebook before assignments finish. Try executing `x = 3; Pause[5]; x = 6;` in one notebook, and quickly switch over to the other and execute `Print[x]`. You'll get 6.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: You probably want to start a new _Mathematica_ kernel per notebook. However, the standard licences allow you to run only two of them. So you might consider to use `Parallel` and its friends instead. Wwith a standard licence, you can run typicall up to 8 parallel kernels (which are slightly less capable than a full kernel). However, doing so requires a bit of practice. And one has to remember that there are some tasks that can be done only by the FrontEnd and there is is only one of the latter.

Comment: If you wish to execute multiple notebooks at once, be sure that they have different contexts, or they may try to talk with each other.